JSON fields in Sphinx
I have a rt index message with title and properties(rt_attr_json) fields:
{     ["title"]=>     string(45) "title1"     ["properties"]=>     string(220) "[{"property_id":1,"value_id": 1},{"property_id":2,"value_id":2}]" } {     ["title"]=>     string(45) "title2"     ["properties"]=>     string(220) "[{"property_id":3,"value_id": 3},{"property_id":4,"value_id":4}]" } 
I need to create a condition by value_id.
How can I get only those records that have an array with value_id = 2 in the properties field?
I tried adding this condition:
->match('@properties.value id 101885656')
but it doesn't work
